# Multiple elements same action

Tags: gui-design, buttons, best-practice, customisation

I have a fundamental question. Is it gonna be a bad UX practice if I use two separate elements, with different UI design, to do the same task?
For example, I wish to have a fancy button on the middle of the landing the page, that does the same thing as my "services" link that could be accessed through clicking Menu > Services on the same page.

Comment: @Ken Mahnkern's answer seems right on the money. It may be worth adding a screen shot or visual mockup to illustrate your point a little more clearly (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll normally want to avoid having different things perform the same function because users are likely to expect different results from different elements.

In your case, though, it sounds like you're treating the fancy button as a shortcut to a feature. It's not uncommon to see calls to action on a homepage that link to internal pages that you could get to through the navigation links.

So I think you're okay.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on a context.

If you are adding another link into the same menu (somewhere else in a hierarchy), use the same design pattern.

If you are adding that link in different context (eg. hero slider or a teaser of some sort), you can use a different design pattern. Your website may and should use multiple design patterns for you CTAs (links, buttons, primary, secondary, etc). As ling as you reuse the design patterns you define - you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Using redundancy to increase usability is absolutely good. Redundancy is not bad per se:

- funnel relevant pages often have a "Go to next step" CTA on top AND on bottom
- Landing pages often have the same CTA with equal functionality that are placed on different scrolling heights of the page
- etc.

Depending on your use case (which is too vague to guess) I would reconsider: Can users reach the item I want to duplicate - do I NEED a duplicate then? Am I only including the duplicate because the original item is not designed well? Does the action I want to copy need special attention because of the use case (Landing page, Funnel importance, ...)?

If you can answer these questions for your usecase, you can take the decision.